# how to iterate the arraylist in the hasmap and again iterate the arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

i have a hashmap like this `HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>>` i am trying to iterate the arryalist in the hash map?

This is what i have tried :

```
for (Entry<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>> entry : testStats.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> value = entry.getValue();
            for(HashMap<String, Integer> aString : value){
                System.out.println("key : " + key + " value : " + aString);
            }
        }
```

But it still shows me only recent value.?

Where i am going wrong?

Comment: Goofy your iterator seems right.. May be at time of inserting values to the HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>> you have used same object

Comment: i have a arrylist of hasmap and ech time i am creatng an object of it and adding this array to my original hashmap? is it because of this

Answer (score 2):

You seem to got confused with your data structure, missing a depth level :

```
for (Entry<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>> entry : testStats.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> list = entry.getValue();
            for(HashMap<String, Integer> map : list){
                   for(Entry<String, Integer> entryInner : map.entrySet){
                        System.out.println("key : " + entryInner.getKey() + " value : " + entryInner.getValue());
                   }
            }
}
```